# PuTTY password prompt changed, can't login

Tags: windows, mac, ssh, passwords, putty

Hey. I've been using PuTTY to SSH into my Mac a bunch. When I did that I got the screen:
`login as: username,
 Using keyboard-interactive authentication,
 Password:`
Which worked fine. But after I tried using a mac Veency app (Screens) and making NO MAJOR CHANGES, it has the prompt `Using username "username"., username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:` and won't accept my (correct) password.

What could have caused this? Does it have to do with the prompt change? How do I change it all back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways Putty can have the username embedded for logging in.

1. In the connect string - such as "username@ww.xx.yy.zz" instead of just "ww.xx.yy.zz"

[image]

2. In the configuration - there is a setting for who to connect as.

[image]

Note the two radio buttons - if that is set to use the system username instead of to prompt it will result in your problem happening.

So there's three possibilities - you have username@... in the connect string, a username in the configuration box, or it is set to not prompt but use your local username.

Comment: Nevermind, My ip address was e.g. xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2 instead of xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1. the interesting thing is it WAS ....xx1, but changed to ....xx2. Thanks anyway.